# MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (211, 6541) and data type <U67

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I'm getting this confusing Python error:

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (211, 6541) and data type <U67`

Firstly, what the heck is `data type <U67`? I can't find anything on Google about it.

Secondly, how do I allocate more than 211 rows to my array? I've got another 5000 or so lists to append to it. I would have though my array is not taking up much space at `211 * 6451 * 8 = 10889288 bytes = 10.889288 megabytes`, so why is there an issue with adding more? Even if I added appended all my lists, it'd still be a comfortable `~270 megabytes`.

My lists look like this:

`['text' 'more text' '1' '0' '0' ... '0' '1' '0']`

And these are repeatedly appended to the array like this:

`array = numpy.append(array,[list],axis = 0)`

Comment: '<U67' means 67 character long unicode.  At 4 bytes per character, that's 268 bytes per element, or 369,880,468 total.

Comment: Repeated `np.append` is slow, even when it works.  It makes a new array each time.  Appending to a list is better (with just one array constructor at the end).  I suspect your text elements vary in length, with one or more 67 characters long. Given the way `numpy` allocates space for strings, the longest string determines the storage for all.

Comment: Following up on what @hpaulj said, numpy arrays may not be the best choice in this scenario. Can you provide some context? What are these strings for?